# QScrollArea not working as expected with QWidget and QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qscrollarea, qframe

So I have this `QFrame` which is the parent widget (represented by `this` in the code). In this widget, I want to place a `QWidget` at 10 px from top (and 10 px from bottom, as a result of which it will have a height of 140px, whereas parent is 160px). The `QWidget` will have a number of custom buttons inside it in a vertical layout, in a scroll area, so that when the height of the buttons combined exceeds the `QWidget's` height (140px), scroll sets in automatically. Because the scroll is not for the entire parent widget, but only for a child widget, the scroll should apply only to the child widget here. Here is my code:

```
//this is a custom button class with predefined height and some formatting styles
class MyButton: public QPushButton
{

public:
    MyButton(std::string aText, QWidget *aParent);

};

MyButton::MyButton(std::string aText, QWidget *aParent): QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(aText), aParent)
{
    this->setFixedHeight(30);
    this->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    this->setCheckable(false);
    this->setStyleSheet("background: rgb(74,89,98);   color: black; border-radius: 0px; text-align: left; padding-left: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;");
}

//this is where I position the parent widget first, and then add sub widget
this->setGeometry(x,y,width,160);
this->setStyleSheet("border-radius: 5px; background:red;");

//this is the widget which is supposed to be scrollable
QWidget *dd = new QWidget(this);
dd->setGeometry(0,10,width,140);
dd->setStyleSheet("background: blue;");

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
dd->setLayout(layout);

for (int i = 0; i < fValues.size(); i++)
{
    MyButton *button = new MyButton(fValues[i],dd);
    layout->addWidget(button);
}

QScrollArea *scroll = new QScrollArea(this);
scroll->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
scroll->setWidget(dd);
```

Contrary to my expectations, this is what I am getting (attached image). What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You messed up the stack of items. The idea of having scrollable area is like this:

- on the bottom is parent widget (for example `QDialog`)
- on top of this is scrollable area (`QScrollArea`) of fixed size
- on top of this is a widget (`QWidget`) of some size, where usually only part of it is visible (it's supposed to be bigger than scrollarea)
- on top of this is a layout
- and the last: layout manages child items (couple of `QPushButton` here)

Try this code:

```
int
main( int _argc, char** _argv )
{
    QApplication app( _argc, _argv );

    QDialog * dlg = new QDialog();
    dlg->setGeometry( 100, 100, 260, 260);

    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea( dlg );
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn );
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable( true );
    scrollArea->setGeometry( 10, 10, 200, 200 );

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    scrollArea->setWidget( widget );

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    widget->setLayout( layout );

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton( QString( "%1" ).arg( i ) );
        layout->addWidget( button );
    }

    dlg->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Worth to mention about `QScrollArea::setWidgetResizable`, which adjusts the child widget size dynamically according to its content.

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for `scrollArea->setWidgetResizable( true );`. Without it, the contained layout doesn't seem to get layouted properly.