# How to show several QTableViews(without scrollbar) in QListWidget(or other similar widgets)?

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qtableview

I have a problem with showing multiple tables(without their own scrollbars) under one scrollbar. Is there any workaround or a good way to resolve this issue in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to do what you ask, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818323/qscrollarea-not-working-as-expected-with-qwidget-and-qvboxlayout). So, here is a solution:

- add `QScrollArea` to a form
- set the property `widgetResizable` to true
- put `QWidget` to scroll area
- right click on widget -> Set ancestor -> [your scroll area]
- add vertical layout to a widget
- scroll area will collapse, epand it with a mouse
- insert into the widget as many tables as you want
- set vertical size policy for each table to `Minimum` and set minimal vertical size.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer. However, can i set each table height equals to it's content? I want to get off the scroll from each table.

Comment: For each table get `verticalHeaderDefaultSize`, multiply it to number of rows and add few pixels, then set minimal vertical size. Also, set property `verticalScrollPolicy` to `ScrollBarAlwaysOff`.